# How can I force a DNS update on a local network?

Tags: networking, mac, dns

I have a Linux laptop that has Wi-Fi and ethernet and I VNC to it from my Mac when it is docked. When it docks, I switch to ethernet via SSH+rfkill. The problem is my mac gets confused when I turn off Wi-Fi on the laptop.

I can see the graphical router network map (WRT1900) and it properly identifies the linuxlaptop as 192.168.1.148, but nslookup, arp and host on the mac are all confused:

```
% sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder

% arp -a -n

% arp 192.168.1.148
? (192.168.1.148) at 8c:fe:fc:f1:f3:f6 on en6 ifscope [ethernet]

% nslookup
> host 192.168.1.148
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find host: No answer
> exit

% host linuxlaptop
linuxlaptop.Home has address 192.168.1.149   <<< this is the rfkill'd wifi address, and is wrong
```

Seems weird nslookup would ask the router for the host name of the IP, and fail, when I can clearly see that the router has the entry on its map.

What other secret commands can I issue on the Mac to update the DNS cache, since flushing it didn't work.

```
% sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.1
BuildVersion:   20C69
```

Comment: Could you please run `sw_vers` and edit your answer to include that output

Comment: It looks like you're using `nslookup` incorrectly. The `nslookup` man page (in macOS Catalina at least) is screwed up on this point. There is no 'host' subcommand. Almost any string you enter at `nslookup`'s `>` prompt is taken to be the hostname you want to look up. So it's literally telling you it can't find an `A` record for the hostname "host".

`nslookup`, `dig`, and `host` each use their own built-in DNS resolver code rather than using the OS's resolver like GUI apps and other commands use. To see the same view of DNS that most of the rest of the OS uses, use `dns-sd -G v4 hostname`.

Comment: Since the `host` command (not the mythical subcommand of `nslookup`) queries DNS servers directly instead of relying on the OS's resolver system, your results from `host` seem to show that your DNS server is still serving up `192.168.1.149` in the `A` record for `linuxlaptop.Home`. I suspect your WRT1900's graphical network map is pulling info from a different source than the DNS server.